# When doing a MySQL INSERT, if the insert fails because of a duplicate key, is there a way to return that key's id?

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

So I have a table like this:

```
create table `test` ( 
`testId` int(11) not null auto_increment, 
`text` varchar(10) not null default '',
primary key(`testId`),
unique(`text`)
) engine=innodb;
```

My insert would be

1. insert into `test` (`text`) values ('a');
2. insert into `test` (`text`) values ('b');
3. insert into `test` (`text`) values ('a');

the 3rd insert will fail, but I want it to return the testId for the duplicate (for 'a').

Is this possible without writing a second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in an INSERT query because the INSERT does not return any rows.

When an INSERT fails because of a duplicated key - normally the thing that built the query knows what data it sent, so it could use this.

You may be able to achieve what you want by using [12.2.5.3. INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column and INSERT ... UPDATE inserts a
>   row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function
>   returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value. If
>   the statement updates a row instead,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful.
>   However, you can work around this by
>   using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose
>   that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column.
>   To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful
>   for updates, insert rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Comment: yeah, i saw that too, was hoping there was a workaround but guess not! just had to break it into two queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this. If you just want to replace the existing data, you can use

```
REPLACE INTO <table_name> VALUES <values>
```

That is the simplest thing. But if you just want to check whether the data exist, you can first, do this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table> WHERE <field>='<field_value>
```

If exists, query returns more than 0.

Hope this helps.